# How to get values from a Key/Value JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Currently working on an asp.net mvc 4 application.

I have a View that is strongly typed.

Inside the View, I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var resultJSON = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Model.Json)));
        console.log(resultJSON);
    });
</script>
```

After I `console.log(resultJSON)`, I get the following result:

```
{
    "Log": {
        "ShowFormatDropdown": true,
        "ShowGroupDropdown": false,
        "ShowStartDateAndYearDropdown": false,
        "ShowEndDateAndYearDropdown": false,
        "ShowStartEndDateTextbox": true,
        "ShowMachineNameDropdown": true,
        "ShowSeverityDropdown": true,
        "ShowSummaryDetailRadioButton": false,
        "ShowMessageTextbox": true,
        "ShowIPAddressTextbox": true,
        "ShowCorrelationTextbox": true,
        "ShowDINTextbox": false
    },
    "RefillRequest": {
        "ShowFormatDropdown": true,
        "ShowGroupDropdown": true,
        "ShowStartDateAndYearDropdown": true,
        "ShowEndDateAndYearDropdown": true,
        "ShowStartEndDateTextbox": false,
        "ShowMachineNameDropdown": false,
        "ShowSeverityDropdown": false,
        "ShowSummaryDetailRadioButton": true,
        "ShowMessageTextbox": false,
        "ShowIPAddressTextbox": false,
        "ShowCorrelationTextbox": false,
        "ShowDINTextbox": false
    },
    "PatientSubscriptions": {
        "ShowFormatDropdown": true,
        "ShowGroupDropdown": true,
        "ShowStartDateAndYearDropdown": true,
        "ShowEndDateAndYearDropdown": true,
        "ShowStartEndDateTextbox": false,
        "ShowMachineNameDropdown": false,
        "ShowSeverityDropdown": false,
        "ShowSummaryDetailRadioButton": true,
        "ShowMessageTextbox": false,
        "ShowIPAddressTextbox": false,
        "ShowCorrelationTextbox": false,
        "ShowDINTextbox": false
    }
}
```

My goal is to have a function in which I can pass a `Key` such as "**RefillRequest**":

```
var settings = mySuperFunction(resultJSON, "RefillRequest");
```

Which in turn, `settings` would be a dictionary holding only the relevant values based on the Key "**RefillRequest**" I passed in.

`settings` would hold something like:

```
"ShowFormatDropdown": true,
"ShowGroupDropdown": true,
"ShowStartDateAndYearDropdown": true,
"ShowEndDateAndYearDropdown": true,
"ShowStartEndDateTextbox": false,
"ShowMachineNameDropdown": false,
"ShowSeverityDropdown": false,
"ShowSummaryDetailRadioButton": true,
"ShowMessageTextbox": false,
"ShowIPAddressTextbox": false,
"ShowCorrelationTextbox": false,
"ShowDINTextbox": false
```

I'm in need of a little help with this since I'm no jQuery/Array/Dictionary expert.

Thanks in advance!
Sincerely

Vince

Comment: Why not just access it using dot notation or square brackets?

Comment: Why you ask? In all honesty, as crazy as it may sound, I didn't think about it and was over thinking it. Luckily people like you are here to help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `resultJSON.RefillRequest`, it will fetch you `RefillRequest` property

As per my understanding, if you need to pass key you can use this

```
var settings = resultJSON["RefillRequest"];
```

Comment: Thank you…you have no idea how over complicated I was looking at this.

Answer (score 1):

No need a function to do that. To access json value you can just.

```
var settings = resultJSON.Log;
//or 
var settings = resultJSON['Log'];
```

Answer (score 1):

While Satpal's answer is correct, you can use this to retrieve the dictionary for *any* key:

```
function mySuperFunction(obj, key) {
    return (key in object) ? object[key] : null;
}
```

So, calling `mySuperFunction(resultJSON, "RefillRequest")` will return `resultJSON.RefillRequest`, or `null` if the key isn't in `resultJSON`.